# clear screen in Fortran

Tags: windows, fortran

I've been searching for a considerably long time for this. Does anyone know how to clear the screen in a console app in Fortran language?
any help will be very much appretiated!

Answer (score 5):

Fortran, *qua* Fortran, knows nothing of such concepts as screens or keyboards or, for that matter, computers.  There is, therefore, no language-standard way of clearing a screen from Fortran.  You will have to find some platform-dependent approach.

Most Fortran compilers have some way of doing this, for example Intel Fortran provides the SYSTEM function.

Comment: +1 It has been so long I can't remember ever clearing the terminal (or needing to clear it)... God I used to love FORTRAN!

Comment: I used the windows batch script command for clearing the screen

    call system ("cls")

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to others I would not call `SYSTEM()` (standard Fortran 2008 alternative is `execute_command_line()`) but I would print right ANSI escape code http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code:

```
print *, achar(27)//"[2J"
```

This will be much faster than calling `SYSTEM()`.

This works in typical Linux terminals, but will not work in the MS Windows terminal.

Another more practical reference how to use the escape code is http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html

Comment: What's the Fortran 2003 standard alternative you refer to ?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html#EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE

Comment: As it says at the link, Fortran 2008 and later, not Fortran 2003.

Comment: You are right, I generally have problems distinguishing f2003 and f2008 as compilers do not implement the features in any order :(

Comment: @VladimirF - "... in any order", what do you mean? They implement them according to the standard they belong to, and user requests. They're not implemented chronologically, if that's what you ment.

Comment: Different vendors support different mix of features from f2003 and f2008. Some features from f2008 are implemented before other features from f2003, but the order is vendor specific.

Answer (score 2):

In Fortran 90/95 your best option is the system command which is a vendor supplied extension (i.e., not part of the F90/95 standard so some obscure Fortran compilers may not have it but all major ones do).

```
$ cat clear.f90
program
call system('clear')
end 
$ gfortran clear.f90 -o clear
$ ./clear
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your specific sytem and compiler. There is no general way. Fortran doesn't know about specific hardware devices like terminal screens and printers. (Neither do most other languages). The details depend entirely on your specific system.

My advice would be to clear the terminal by invoking the relevent script via the command line - but this is not nice. it is generally more portable to write the output to an ordinary text file and then execute appropriate system commands to print that file to screen. This way you can manipulate the file as you wish...

See [here](http://objectmix.com/fortran/35090-clear-screen.html) for a simalar question from which these some of the above text was salvaged.

Answer (score 1):

In Fortran `ACHAR(N)` returns the ASCII of N, so my preferred method would be:

```
WRITE(*,'(2f15.9,A5)',advance='no') float1,float2,ACHAR(13)
```

`ACHAR(13)` returns carriage return character `\r` in Python. So after printing, it returns the cursor to the beginning of the line where it can be overwritten.

After you are out of the loop you can use `CALL SYSTEM('clear')` to clean the screen.

This is helpful since `CALL SYSTEM('clear')` is slower and uses a lot of CPU, you can check this by replacing the above method with

```
WRITE(*,'(2f15.9)',advance='no') float1,float2;CALL SYSTEM('clear')
```

and check the difference in time taken in loops.

Comment: This is more of a clear line than clear screen, though. Specifically the same the escape code 1 G would do, move cursor to column 1.

Comment: @VladimirF this ASCII 13 thing doesn't work in all terminals either, is there any alternative way? `print *, achar(27)//"[2J"` doesn't really seem to stay static on the page for me.

Comment: Depends on your exact purpose. My answer was really just for clearing the screen and nothing more. If you need to write something on a static place on the screen, ASCII 13 is not bad. The alternative is `print *, achar(27)//"[1G"` but it is pretty much the same as ASCII 13 and also only works on some terminals.

Comment: @VladimirF how about printing characters in the file clear.txt after `clear > clear.txt`? It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This Works For Me in FTN95

```
program
call system('CLS')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found yet another way to clear screen in UNIX like systems by printing the output of `clear` command 
 (from manual of clear command which states you can write the output to a file and then `cat` it to clear the screen)

So better way is to `clear > temp.txt` and use the characters in files in a print statement

Although both do the same thing, calling SYSTEM("foo") is very very (100+ times) slower than directly printing those characters

For example:

```
program clear
    implicit none
    INTEGER::i
    do i = 1, 1000
        print *, "Test"
        call system("clear")
    enddo
end program clear
```

This program takes anywhere between **3.1 to 3.4** seconds.

But instead of calling system, if I directly print the characters like this :

```
program clear
    implicit none
    INTEGER::i
    do i = 1, 1000
        print *, "Test"
        print *, "[H[2J[3J"
    enddo
end program clear
```

This produces the exact same result but takes anywhere between **0.008 to 0.012** seconds (8 to 12 ms)

In fact, running the second loop 100,000 is faster than `CALL SYSTEM("clear")` 1000 times

**EDIT: Don't copy-paste from here, it won't work, (characters are replaced on StackOverflow)**

Just use `clear > file` and copy the contents of the file into a print statement

Screenshot of actual code(from preview): 
[image: screenshot]
These characters aren't supported I guess, They disappear in the answers (They work fine in preview)

Comment: @VladimirF  don't think so, the escape code in your answer behaves somewhat like 'ctrl+L'  for me, like the screen gets cleared but cursor doesn't return,something like that. Like all written characters on terminal are replaced with blank space characters

Comment: There is 2J and 3J, they are quite similar:  *If n is 2, clear entire screen (and moves cursor to upper left on DOS ANSI.SYS). If n is 3, clear entire screen and delete all lines saved in the scrollback buffer (this feature was added for xterm and is supported by other terminal applications).* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: @VladimirF IDK, even `print *,achar(27) // "[H[2J[3J"` isn't producing the exact result as `CALL SYSTEM("clear")`

Comment: Yes, I am trying to understand what exactly it actually does. Whether it is a Unix-terminal specific and why there is the `[2J` in common.

Comment: @VladimirF Check my edit, a character goes missing in the answer but works in the preview

Comment: Okay I have figured it out, the missing character is ASCII 27

`print *,achar(27),"[H",achar(27),"[2J",achar(27),"[3J"` 

This works as intended

Comment: That's what I supposed. This is exactly the ANSI/CSI sequence 2J and 3J I linked.

Comment: 3J seems optional but [H seems important to not leave behind emply characters