# How to print on a specific line and column in Fortran console?

Tags: interface, terminal, fortran, intel-fortran

I want to write data in console in random position. For example, if there 25 rows by 80 symbols and I want to write some number or char to second row and 60 symbol, I use something like this:

```
CALL Gprint(60,2,'H')
```

or this:

```
CALL Gprint(80,25,Arr)
```

where `Arr` - 80*25 array of characters.

I am using Intel Fortran XE 14.

Comment: All you can do is write appropriate control codes for your console to stdout.  If you have a vt100 compatible console (mode linux-ish terminals) for example the codes are well documented and pretty simple to implement in fortran.

Comment: You should tell us which OS you use. The escape codes are here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code They will not work in the Windows terminal, but you don't need a specific vt100 compatible. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10919072/721644 for an example. A practical guide is  http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html

Comment: *"some code or library to detect position of mouse click"* belong somewhere else. It would belong to a different question, but it is off-topic anyway.

Comment: I am using windows+intel fortran+vs2012.
>It would belong to a different question, but it is off-topic anyway
hah, topic question is off-topic?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran does not do by itself what is asked; conventional approaches to this use curses (ncurses), termcap (or terminfo).  Given the compiler, that sounds like a Linux system.  You may find this useful:

- [A public-domain Fortran(2003) interface to the ncurses(3c) library](http://www.urbanjost.altervista.org/LIBRARY/libscreen/ncurses/pdsrc/ncurses_from_Fortran.html)
- [Programming Answers to Common Questions about Fortran](http://www.glue.umd.edu/afs/glue.umd.edu/system/info/olh/Programming/Answers_to_Common_Questions_about_FORTRAN/fortran_call_c)

If it were Windows, that specific question has already been asked:

- [Does an ncurses or similar library exist which works well with fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207032/does-an-ncurses-or-similar-library-exist-which-works-well-with-fortran)